# Iteration on 2 arrays (single and multidimensional) in 1 go

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm building an extension on `PDOStatement` to auto bind values on `named` or `?` params on execution in the style of the [bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) function in `mysqli`. I want it to work a little like this:

```
  // Named params, converted to int and str.
  $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :a AND somecol = :b')->run('is', [':a' => 69, ':b' => 'somestring']);

  // Index params, converted to double and lob (else statement, ignore this)
  $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE coord = ? AND img = ?')->run('dl', $coord, $img);
```

---

I've added the following function to a class extending `PDOStatement`:

```
    public function run(string $types, ...$args){
        foreach($args as $var){
            if(is_array($var)){ 
                // this is the code for the :named params.
                if(count($types = str_split($types)) == count($var)){
                    // the types string matches the length of the given arguements.

                    $i = 0;
                    array_walk($var, function($val,$key) use ($types, $i){
                        echo $key, '=>', $val, '->', $types[++$i], '<br>'; 

                    });
                } else {
                    // error, length of types does not match the length of the array.
                }
            } else {
                // This is the code for ? params.
            }
        }
    }
```

The output: `:a=>69->i` and `:b=>somestring->i`. Obviously the `$i` does not increment but the issue is that both array's are different, where i use `$types = str_split($types)` to the following array:

```
    $types = [
      0 => 'i',
      1 => 's'
    ];

    $var = [
      ':a' => 69,
      ':b' => 'somestring',
    ];
```

A solution would be to loop of `$var` with foreach and increment the $i inside the loop to refer to the `$types[$i]` so I get set a param.

The problem is that I want to do this *as efficient* as possible meaning I want to do this in 1 iteration preferably not even using the `$i` variable.

I'm running blanks on how loop both array's as perhaps there is a function I forgot about.

---

**I've found a solution to this, what a good night sleep can do:**
My solution was using `array_shift()` to fetch and remove the first numeric key from `$types` returning its value.

```
private function getParam($type){
    switch($type){
        case 's':
        case 'f':
        case 'd': return PDO::PARAM_STR;
        case 'i': return PDO::PARAM_INT;
        case 'b': return PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
        case 'n': return PDO::PARAM_NULL;
        case 'l':
        case 'r': return PDO::PARAM_LOB;
        default:
            // should log this issue.
            return PDO::PARAM_STR;
    }
}

public function run(string $types, ...$args){
    $t = str_split($types);
    $i = 1;

    foreach($args as $var){
        if(is_array($var)){ 
            if(count($t) == count($var)){
                foreach($var as $key => $val){
                    $this->bindValue($key, $val, $this->getParam(array_shift($t)));
                }
            } else {
                throw new StatementError('1 type should be set for each arguement');
            }
        } else {
            // No error checks, perhaps let PDO take care of it entirely instead
            $this->bindValue($i++, $var, $this->getParam(array_shift($t)));
        }
    }

    $this->result = $this->execute();
    return $this;
}

private function __construct($dbh){
    $this->dbh = $dbh;
}
```

Comment: You don't need this stuff. Just make your execute return $this and run your PDO queries like this `$db->prepare($sql)->execute($data);`

Comment: That would be the default method of doing this if you want to bind everything to a string. However while MySQL generously accepts integers as strings other databases don't. I'm not overwriting the the function `execute` just making a 1 liner function where I can bind int\lob\null\bool types without having to bind them manually. However I've found a solution to this, using `array_shift($types)`

Comment: If you're using custom types, then it will be good to add some. say, "a" for comma-delimited values. You will find it enormously handy to run a query like this `$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM t WHERE id IN(?)")->run("a",$ids);` just think what code you will need to run such a query with your current approach.

Comment: Oops, forgot to fix it, `run("a",[$ids])`it should be, as $args have to be an array explicitly.

Comment: Your first example is actually correct with this setup as the first expects multiple args `?` and `:named` parameters expects the first arg to an array. However using the `IN` clause PDO would expect IN(?,?,etc) in the SQL string. Since the string has been prepared already its impossible to change it. However that does not mean I can't add a function that allows for SQL manipulation before preparing it so your idea is possible and very much extendable with type conversions (hex2bin, etc).

Comment: Oh. I didn't notice you made it *this* way. You'll pull all your hair out in less than a week of using this terrible approach. Listen to good advise, do it as execute() does - just accept single array of args.

Comment: I'm not neglecting your advice as obviously I want to improve upon. Perhaps I'm not getting what you mean because `run()` does exactly what `execute()` does in the way it takes arguments. The only difference is the first arg containing type definitions like `bind_param()` in mysqli the following args are handled the same. Perhaps elaborate with an answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102354/discussion-between-xorifelse-and-your-common-sense).